# Check to see if category is populated?

Tags: entries, templating, categories

I want to list all categories that have an entry assigned to them, but hide the ones that are empty.

In EE I could do this `show_empty="no"`

But I can't see a parameter in the docs for Craft.

Currently I've found that I could use relatedTo but with passing an object with up to 600 entries it dies with caching tags :(

Is there a better way of doing this? This is what I've got at the moment:

```
{% set blogPosts = craft.entries({section:'blog',limit:null}).find() %}

{% for cat in craft.categories({groupId:2}).relatedTo(blogPosts) %}
   <li><a href="/blog/{{cat.slug}}">{{cat.title}}</a> </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a great tutorial over at [Straight Up Craft](http://straightupcraft.com/articles/how-do-i-only-display-a-list-of-categories-that-have-entries-and-hide-empty-categories) for handling this (it is however very similar to what you have - it may speed things up a tad though).

> First, we want to grab all of the entry ids from the Section of
>   content which we want to display categories for.
>
> `{% set entryIds = craft.entries.section('blog').ids() %}`
>
> Next, we will use the craft.categories tags relatedTo() method to only
>   return categories that have a relationship with one of our entry ids.
>
> `{% set categories = craft.categories.relatedTo({ sourceElement:
>   entryIds }).groupId(1).find() %}`
>
> Once we have our list of categories that are in use, we can loop
>   through those categories and display them in our template:
>
> ```
> {% for category in categories %}
>     <li><a href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.title }}</a></li>
> {% endfor %}
> ```