# Author List, Only Users With Entry

Tags: users

I am trying to show a list of users but only if they have created a post in a certain section... the code I am using isn't working as expected. Perhaps I have the syntax wrong when it comes to the user model

Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('news') %}
{% set authorList = craft.users.relatedTo(entries) %}

{% for author in authorList %}
<h5><a href="/news/author/{{author.username}}">{{author.fullName}}</a></h5>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
{# Grab all the entries for the section #}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('news').find() %}

{# Group by the authorId #}
{% set entriesByAuthor = entries|group('authorId') %}

{# Grab all of the users with the userIds in entriesByAuthor #}
{% set authors = craft.users.id(entriesByAuthor|keys) %}

<ul>
    {% for author in authors %}
        <li>{{ author.username }}
    {%  endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks as always!! Why doesn't it work with the usual relatedTo parameter?

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to [another question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1345/check-to-see-if-category-is-populated), and should yield the same results:

```
{% set entryIds = craft.entries.section('news').ids() %}
{% set authorList = craft.users.relatedTo({ sourceElement: entryIds }).find() %}
```

With this you are basically saying, "I'm looking for users related to these news entries where the news entry is where the user is set".

Comment: I tried a version like that previously and I also just tested the snippet above and it isn't working : ( That is definitely how I would expect it to work... that's why I thought maybe there was something I was missing.

Comment: This only works with a user relationship field on the entry, or a entries relationship field on the user. This does not work for the Author field on entries.